# PHP exec() pkill works, but not kill. Why?

Tags: php, shell

When making a PHP script for a website to kill a process, this works to kill all processes with that name...

```
<?PHP exec ("pkill linuxjampded"); ?>
```

But killing them via a specific port doesn't...

```
<?PHP exec('kill -9 $(lsof -i:29070 -t)'); ?>
```

Why? When testing this using the php command in shell...

> php -r "echo exec('kill -9 $(lsof -i:29070 -t)');"

It executes and kills the process via that port number just fine.

If there is another way to kill a process via its port either using .sh or PHP script that would help me out a ton.

Answer (score 1):

I found out why. It was the lsof command. http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/lsof-command-not-found-centos-906882/

When using this, I was able to find the real issue...

```
$result = shell_exec("/home/cmcomp/public_html/gameserver/gsk.sh 2>&1");
echo "<pre>$result</pre>";
```

The .sh file holds the command...

```
kill -9 $(/usr/sbin/lsof -i:29070 -t)
```